# Can't run unity-control-center

Tags: unity, system-settings, unity-control-center

If anyone knows whats causing this I'd appreciate it

```
➜  ~  unity-control-center 

(unity-control-center:1895): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'unity-control-center' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 166 error_code 2 request_code 155 (GLX) minor_code 24)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
[1]    1895 trace trap (core dumped)  unity-control-center
```

I found a bug report about a Nvidia driver causing something similar but I'm running an Amd driver

Answer (score 0):

I did `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-346` and `sudo apt-get remove system76-driver-nvidia`, then rebooted the machine and then System Settings worked.

On a weird side note: I haven't been able to get HDMI working at all (yet displayport did work). After the removal - it worked as well.